# SSL Certificate for Email Server

Tags: asp.net, email, ssl, tls1.2

Here is the scenario, I have a web application (ASP.NET) and mail server reside on the same server. my website is using a single domain SSL Certificate and my mail is configured as mail.mydomain.com

When I send emails through my web application or the mail client they end up in the junk mail because they are not secured. So I would like to use SSL/TLS Certificate for the mail.mydomain.com

My question is how to do that? can I purchase any separate SSL Certificate for mail.mydomain.com or is there any specific requirement that should be done prior to that.

I'm using Windows Server 2012 and SmarterMail for the mail server (Both on the same server)

Comment: What do you mean by junk mail?

Comment: I mean the Junk/Spam folder

Comment: Unsure if there is a (any) relationship with "junk mail" and SSL/TLS when "sending mail through your application". Typically, these things involve proper `DNS` settings for `spf` and `domain keys`. Unless of course, your host is in some blacklist (IP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your email domain is different from your web domain (I assume nobody actually navigates to https://mail.mydomain.com) you need one of the following:

1. Two SSL certs with [FQDN](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aiuv)
2. A single cert with [wildcard subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)
3. Multi-subject cert, i.e. a certificate with a [Subject Alternative Name](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm)

Frankly #1 is probably the easiest, and may not even cost more-- wildcard and multi-domain certs carry an additional charge, and there are limitations on when you can use them (for example, CA's may not issue a wildcard [EV cert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)).

See also [this article on InfoSec SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54017/ssl-certificate-for-an-email-server).

Comment: my email domian is a subdomain of the main website. For Example: my website is mydomain.com and the email domain is mail.mydomain.com

Comment: Unless you have a wildcard cert, you need a complete match of the FQDN including `mail.`

Comment: So is it possible to have another SSL Certificate for only the subdomain mail.mydomain.com? if yes, is there any specific certificate for this use or any certificate can do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to purchase a separate SSL certificate for the mail.domain.com so it can work like https://mail.domain.com

Following is the steps to install SSL on Smartermail.

==> Export SSL Certificate to a Base-64 Encoded Certificate :-

(1) Connect to your VPS/Server through Remote Desktop where you have installed SmarterMail.
  (2) Click Start, select Run. Type MMC, hit enter.
  (3) Open File >> Add\Remove Snap ins.
  (4) From the list of available snap-ins, select Certificates and hit Add.
  (5) A new window will appear, choose Computer account and hit Next.
      Ensure local computer is selected and hit Finish.
  (6) In certificate tree view, expand Personal and choose Certificates.
  (7) Right click on certificate you wish to export >> All Tasks >> Export.
  (8) A new window will appear, hit Next.
  (9) Select No, do not export private key >> Next.

(10) Save the certificate as Base 64 x509 .cer file >> Next.
  (12) Save the certificate at location C:\SmarterMail\Certificates\mail.domain.com. Name the certificate and click Save.

==> Add Ports to Listen Over SSL/TLS at SmarterMail :-

(1) Login to SmarterMail as admin user.
  (2) Click on Settings icon.
  (3) Expand the Bindings folder and click Ports in the navigation pane.
  (4) Click New in the content pane toolbar. A popup window will display.
  (5) Enter required fields;

(A) Protocol : SMTP
(B) Encryption : SSL
(C) Name : SMTP SSL
(D) Port : 465
(E) Certificate Path : C:/Smartermail/Certificates/mail.domain.com
(F) Discription : certificate

(6) Click on Verify Certificate to ensure the certificate exists in the specified path.
  (7) Click on Save.
  (8) Using above steps, add POP3, SMTP and IMAP ports to be encrypted with SSL or TLS.

==> Add Secure Ports to Listen on SmarterMail IP address

(1) Log in to SmarterMail as admin user.
  (2) Click on Settings icon.
  (3) Expand the Bindings folder and click IP Addresses in the navigation pane.
  (4) Select desired IP address and click Edit.
  (5) Binding IP Address
  (6) Use the checkboxes to select the port(s) you would like the IP address to listen on.
  (7) Click Save.
  (8) Restart SmarterMail service.

Now, you can work with SSL for SmarterMail.